# spring: creating my own @Value / autowiring based on parameter

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

`@Value` provides different objects based on it's parameter. I would like to do something similar. i want to create a bean factory that takes a parameter and creates a bean

```
public MyBean factoryMethod(String input) {...}
```

and i want to autowire that bean:

```
@SomeAnnotation("input for bean factory")
MyBean myBean;
```

is it possible with spring?

Comment: I believe, it is not good idea to mix injection and instantiation. Because this are different things. For example: what Spring should to do if you will declare injection for same bean with different parameters in different places?

Comment: spring should do exactly the same it does for `@Value` - it should invoke the factoryMethod with parameter (if prototype) or use cached instance (if singleton)